# Bitcoin transaction not in my wallet

Tags: wallet

Transaction ID
BE105753
Order Type
BUY
Status
COMPLETED
BTC
0.00758253
Created
17/08/2023 05:21
Crypto Wallet
bc1p07uleun0j0d50uwhd9m3dadh59pd3xm35jplu54m78w35smpsynqrtf42v
Blockchain Link
https://blockchain.com/btc/tx/b693d9aefc5285f069c0daef8be372f8bf412c349a985e4913b7ebafd0e06456
Total Amount
235 EUR

Comment: Hi, this is a question and answer platform. Could you please include a question in this post? It would also help if you let us know what you were trying to do, how this outcome differs from your expectations and who your counterparty was.

Answer (score 0):

> **Bitcoin transaction not in my wallet**

Assuming you mean a Bitcoin transaction was made to pay money to an address generated by your wallet but your wallet is not showing the money as being received:

That [transaction](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/b693d9aefc5285f069c0daef8be372f8bf412c349a985e4913b7ebafd0e06456) has a thousand confirmations, so the money is "at" the [address](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/bc1p07uleun0j0d50uwhd9m3dadh59pd3xm35jplu54m78w35smpsynqrtf42v) you mentioned.

Your wallet should have a record of that address.

If your wallet doesn't show the money, there is something wrong with your wallet but remember that wallets don't contain money, they only contain the secret numbers known as private keys. The private keys give you control over money, the ability to spend received money. After having generated the receiving address passed to the sender, the receiving wallet plays no active part in the actual receipt of money - it just has to learn that it has happened in order to be able to show you that it has happened.

Comment: Why "secret keys" for "private keys"? Are we using new terminology globally or is it just syntactic sugar just for this post?

Comment: @Mercedes, just a typo really. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed.